# UICollectionView Cells not updating when associated data is updated

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionview, and each cell has an 'empty star' button. When the user taps on that button, the image of the button should become a 'filled star.' The collectionview should sort itself so that the cell with the 'filled star' is first, and any previous cell that had a 'filled star' should now have an 'empty star' image.

My problem is that when the user taps another cell, with an 'empty star' image, it does update the image on that cell and the sorting occurs, but the previous cell doesn't update (i.e. it still shows a filled star rather than an empty star). Can anyone take a look and see what's happening? I've posted a minimum reproducible example (it's a view you should be able to just constrain to a view controller).

```
protocol ObjectCollectionViewDelegate {
    func refreshStarred(object: Object)
}

class ObjectCollectionView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var objects = [Object]()
    
    var starredObject: Object?
    
    lazy var collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: createCollectionViewLayout())
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Object>?
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        self.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true
        
        setUpDataSource()
        
        collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: Cell.self))
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        self.objects = [Object(name: "First"), Object(name: "Second"), Object(name: "Third"), Object(name: "Fourth")]
        
        self.refreshSnapshot()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    // Called via lazy initialization of collectionview
    private func createCollectionViewLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.5))
        
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)
        
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: itemSize, subitems: [item])
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    }
    
    private func setUpDataSource() {
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Object>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView, indexPath, object) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            
            
            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: Cell.self),
                for: indexPath) as? Cell else {
                fatalError("ObjectPicker -Could not cast cell as \(Cell.self)")
            }
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.object = object
            return cell
        }
        
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSource
        
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Object>()
        snapshot.appendSections([0])
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    }
}

extension ObjectCollectionView: ObjectCollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func refreshStarred(object: Object) {
        
        // Unstar the previously starred object (if any)
        if let previouslyStarredObject = starredObject {
            previouslyStarredObject.isStarredObject = false
        }

        // Star the newly tapped object
        object.isStarredObject = true
        starredObject = object

        self.refreshSnapshot()
    }
    
    func refreshSnapshot() {
        
        guard let dataSource = dataSource else { return }
        
        var objectsToRefreshWith = [Object]()
        
        if self.objects.count == 0 {
            self.starredObject = nil
        } else if self.objects.count == 1 {
            objectsToRefreshWith.append(objects[0])
            objects[0].isStarredObject = true
            starredObject = objects[0]
        } else if self.starredObject == nil && objects.count > 0 {
            objects[0].isStarredObject = true
            starredObject = objects[0]
            
            for object in objects {
                if object != starredObject {
                    object.isStarredObject = false
                }
                objectsToRefreshWith.append(object)
            }
        } else if self.starredObject != nil {
            
            guard let primary = objects.first(where: { $0.isStarredObject }) else {
                print("Object Picker - the primary Object specified is not in the objects array")
                return
            }
            
            objectsToRefreshWith.append(primary)
            for object in objects where object != primary {
                if object != starredObject {
                    object.isStarredObject = false
                }
                objectsToRefreshWith.append(object)
            }
        }
        
        var snapShot = dataSource.snapshot(for: 0)
        snapShot.applyDifferences(newItems: objectsToRefreshWith)
        dataSource.apply(snapShot, to: 0, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var delegate: ObjectCollectionViewDelegate?
    
    var object: Object? {
        didSet {
            if let object = object {
                self.label.text = object.name
            }
        }
    }
    
    var button = UIButton()
    
    let label = UILabel()
    
    var imageConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 24)
    
    var isStarredObject: Bool {
        get { return object?.isStarredObject ?? false }
        set { object?.isStarredObject = newValue }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.233, alpha: 1)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        
        
        self.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
        self.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "star", withConfiguration: imageConfig)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouched), for: .allTouchEvents)
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func updateButton() {
        
        guard let delegate = delegate else {
            print("No object or delegate assigned to cell")
            return
        }
        
        if isStarredObject {
            let newImage = UIImage(systemName: "star.fill", withConfiguration: imageConfig)
            self.button.setImage(newImage, for: .normal)
            self.button.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            let newImage = UIImage(systemName: "star", withConfiguration: imageConfig)
            self.button.setImage(newImage, for: .normal)
            self.button.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
    @objc func buttonTouched() {
        
        guard let object = object else {
            print("No object or delegate assigned to cell")
            return
        }
        
        self.delegate?.refreshStarred(object: object)

        self.updateButton()
    }
}

class Object: Codable {

    var name: String
    var isStarredObject: Bool = false
    
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension Object: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}


extension NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot {
    
    mutating func applyDifferences(newItems: [ItemIdentifierType]) {
        
        guard self.items != newItems else { return }
        
        let differences = newItems.difference(from: self.items)
        
        for difference in differences {
            switch difference {
            case let .insert(offset: offset, element: item, _):
                if self.items.isEmpty {
                    self.append([item])
                } else if offset == 0 {
                    self.insert([item], before: self.items[0])
                } else {
                    self.insert([item], after: self.items[offset - 1])
                }
            case let .remove(offset: _, element: item, _):
                self.delete([item])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Even though I was updating the 'Objects', and the datasource was instructing the collectionview to update the *position* of the cells, it was not updating the *content* of the cells.

What I needed to do is instead retrieve the index of each cell and manually force it to update the content. So looking at my code above, in the function 'refreshSnapshot', just under where I define the datasource, I added this line:

```
    var snapShot = dataSource.snapshot(for: 0)
    
    for eachObject in objectsToRefreshWith {
        guard let index = snapShot.index(of: eachObject), let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)) as? Cell else {
            print("RefreshSnapshot - Could not get cell for \(eachObject)")
            continue
        }
        cell.updateButton()
                                                                                    
    }
    
    snapShot.applyDifferences(newItems: objectsToRefreshWith)
    dataSource.apply(snapShot, to: 0, animatingDifferences: true)
```

I know that if I'm only targeting a single cell, I don't need to iterate over every object, but this function is also going to be used when data is loaded in from other sources, and I don't necessarily know if the Objects loaded in will have the 'isStarred' property set to true.

If anyone can think of a more efficient solution, I'm happy to hear it!